# What's the best practice to make Meteor, Webstorm and Typescript work together?

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, webstorm

I use Webstorm to manage Meteor project, and I'm fancy with the strong-type checking provided by Typescript.

There are two options to convert Typescript to js, one is by the file watcher of Webstorm, another is to add meteortypescript:compiler.

The former seems more strict, because it will complain if I not add the correct reference, but it cannot deal with existing files, do I have to add the generated js files to VCS? Otherwise other team members must manually generate the files after updating from VCS.

On the other hand, generating by meteortypescript:compiler, makes the tests in tests/jasmine ignored by velocity, which are written in Typescript and not generate js files in the same path.

And which definition files should I use?

`meteor add typescript-libs`

does not add any .d.ts in my project, how to refer them?

`mrt add typescript-libs`

adds typescript-libs in packages folder, but it seems out of date.

`tsd query meteor --action install`

installs a later version of meteor.d.ts, but can not find iron:router and some other definition files.

Comment: Favorited - though curious if possible to do so properly. I have tried Webstorm with Meteor but found it a bit slow compared to Sublime Text which I am trying out now.
I hope you get a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Add the following packages to your project.

```
meteor add meteortypescript:typescript-libs
meteor add meteortypescript:compiler
```

Add to your `.gitignore` >> `.ts`

And for every .ts file you create (which will compile to JS) you place at the first line EXACTLY HOW IT IS:

```
/// <reference path=".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteortypescript_typescript-libs/definitions/all-definitions.d.ts" />
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Why would you need to add the `/// <reference path=".meteor/local/...` line?